# Decode data from nextion display [python]

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to communicate with a nextion display over serial in python. Here is my code so far:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
EndCom = "\xff\xff\xff"
ser.write('n0.val'+EndCom)
```

That should tell the nextion to return the value of `n0`, which is 4.

`ser.inWaiting()` returns 4.

`ser.read(4)` returns `'\x00\xff\xff\xff'`.

I am unable to decode this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `struct.unpack` which unpacks strings according to a given format. In this case your format will be `'i'` which means 4 bytes integer.

```
>>> import struct
>>> result = struct.unpack('i', '\x00\xff\xff\xff')
>>> result[0]
-256
```

From the docs:

> The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item.

Answer (score 0):

The code should read:

```
ser.write('get n0.val'+EndCom)
```

What I had before was not returning the correct value.